# Drupal6 - Node import

Tags: drupal-6, import

Hi
I have used [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) to export a mass of node as a csv file, I would like to update these nodes and import to the drupal so as to **REPLACE** the existing node(not creating new node).

Which modules or method can do with it("import and REPLACE the existing node"), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Feeds Module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).  Here is a link to its [Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/622696).

Feeds is pretty easy to use.  It will allow you to choose a node type, map fields between the CSV and your content type, allow you to replace the nodes, and more.

- First you need to create a new importer at "www.example.com/admin/build/feeds/create"
- Then you need to configure the settings at "www.example.com/admin/build/feeds/edit/NAME_OF_IMPORTER"
- Basically to replace nodes for **Parser** you want `CSV Parser`, for **Processor** you want `Node processor`, and most likely `File Upload` for the **Fetcher** setting.
- Click on the "Mapping" link next to *Node processor* to setup your desired CSV->Content type field mapping
- Import your CSV at "www.example.com/import/NAME_OF_IMPORTER"

You may need to tweak a few more specific settings, but this module should do what you are asking.